# Google Cloud Firestore - URL was not found on this server

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

We have troubles accessing Google Firestore from our java application. We use the following library to access firestore: `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:1:32:2`

How we use it(kotlin):

```
class MyFirestore(private val firestore: Firestore) {
...
override fun findById(id: Long): Optional<Configuration> {
        val documentSnapshot = awaitFuture(firestore.collection(docName()).document(id.toString()).get())
        return if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
            Optional.ofNullable(documentSnapshot.toObject(docClass()))
        } else {
            Optional.empty()
        }
    }

}
```

The error we get:

```
2020-03-02 13:03:15,041 ERROR [http-nio-7300-exec-10] c.i.f.a.d.MyFirestore - Unable to execute firestore query for 'myconfiguration' document
2020-03-02 13:03:15,049 ERROR [http-nio-7300-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path /myService threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.my.service.exception.FirestoreQueryException: Unable to execute firestore query for 'myconfiguration' document] with root cause
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: HTTP status code 404
invalid content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
headers: Metadata(:status=404,content-type=text/html; charset=UTF-8,referrer-policy=no-referrer,content-length=1608,date=Mon, 02 Mar 2020 12:03:15 GMT)
DATA-----------------------------

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
<style>
{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px} > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}insa img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}





at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectStreamController$ResponseObserverAdapter.onClose(GrpcDirectStreamController.java:149)
at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700)
at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:521)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:641)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:529)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:703)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:692)
at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

It doesn't matter if the collection exists in firestore or not. Also the same code works in other Google Projects. The error message is really weird since it is HTML...

Anyone know how to deal with that?

Comment: Are you sure the document exists inside the collection? A 404 code is returned when a resource couldn't be found.
Also the HTML message is strange, is it made by you? The string "Error 404 (Not Found)!!1" suggests that someone did.

Comment: The collection exists. The error message is directly from the API or this library com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore. I didn't modify it.

Comment: The CSS from the response especially "background:url" leaves me with the assumption that it is a direct response from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this issue happens when a partner interconnect to Google Cloud is used and the API isn't enabled for you.

Comment: Please accept your own answer if you found the issue and you managed to solve it. This way you will be helping the community whenever somebody faces the same problem.